# Haptic feedback in Compact Framework 2 running on Windows Mobile 6.5

Tags: compact-framework, vibration

I'm writing a Compact Framework 2.0 application on Windows Mobile 6.5

Several of the built-in controls (e.g. button) produce haptic feedback - small vibrations - when clicked.

Is there any way the same thing can be achieved in custom controls?

I'm aware of some platform specific APIs for this - but I'm looking for a generic WM6.5 API to call if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "generic" managed Windows Mobile mechanism for this.  Your best bet is to abstract the implementation into an interface, then have it determine at run time what you're running on and instantiate the implementation based on that.

The [LED notification API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms895427.aspx) is probably the most common implementation by OEMs and I think would cover the majority.